# org-export latex pdf output does not render svg

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-babel

I tried out this section of code from [this repo](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dfeich/org-babel-examples/master/latex/latex-example.org)

```
#+LATEX_HEADER_EXTRA: \usepackage{svg}

...

#+PROPERTY: header-args :eval never-export :file-ext svg

...

#+NAME: sequence12422
#+BEGIN_SRC plantuml :file-ext png
  ' this is a comment
  Alice -> Bob: Authentication Request
  Bob --> Alice: Authentication Response
  John --> Alice: another Authentication Request
  Alice --> John: another Authentication Response
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS: sequence12422
[[file:sequence12422.png]]

#+NAME: svg-seq
   #+BEGIN_SRC plantuml
     ' this is a comment
     Alice -> Bob: Authentication Request
     Bob --> Alice: Authentication Response
     John --> Alice: another Authentication Request
     Alice --> John: another Authentication Response
   #+END_SRC

   #+RESULTS: svg-seq
   [[file:svg-seq.svg]]
```

the png image gets rendered but the svg does not. My org-version is 9.1.9 on macOS mojave. What is the proper way to render svg images on pdf with org export? Am I missing a package or something?

EDIT: In the exported `tex` file, the exists no command that includes the svg image. However, I can see the `\includegraphics{...}` for my png image.

Answer (score 3):

I posted an issue on the author's [github repo](https://github.com/dfeich/org-babel-examples/issues/6).

You need to:

1. install inkscape (macOS: `brew install caskformula/caskformula/inkscape --HEAD --branch-0.92`)
2. set `org-latex-pdf-process` with the `-shell-escape` switch.

```
     (setq org-latex-pdf-process
       (let
           ((cmd (concat "pdflatex -shell-escape -interaction nonstopmode"
                 " --synctex=1"
                 " -output-directory %o %f")))
         (list cmd
           "cd %o; if test -r %b.idx; then makeindex %b.idx; fi"
           "cd %o; bibtex %b"
           cmd
           cmd)))
```

3. make sure the svg image is in the same directory as the file that includes it

Check the conversation in the repo for more details.